# User Object in Meteor, losing email and roles fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

as the title says, my user object is losing fields once it reaches the client side.

Here is a list of packages I am using:

- accounts-password         1.1.0
- alanning:roles            1.2.13
- autopublish               1.0.3
- insecure                  1.0.3
- iron:router               1.0.7
- jquery                    1.11.3_2
- meteor-platform           1.2.2
- mizzao:jquery-ui          1.11.2
- mquandalle:jade           0.4.1
- semantic:ui-css           1.11.5
- useraccounts:core         1.8.1
- useraccounts:semantic-ui  1.8.1

Here is my client code. In a template events

```
var firstname = $("#firstname").val()
var lastname = $("#lastname").val()
var email = $("#email").val()
Meteor.call("createAdmin", firstname, lastname, email, function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); 
    }
}
```

Here is my server code, meteor method:

```
createAdmin: function(firstname, lastname, email) {
   var loggedInUser = Meteor.user()
   if (!loggedInUser || !Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['dc-admin'])) {
     throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Access denied")
   } else {
     var id;
     id = Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: "testpassword",
       profile: { first_name: firstname, last_name: lastname }
     });
     Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, ['dc-admin']);
     return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: id});
   }
 },
```

If I log the returned result on the client side I get something like this:

```
{"_id":"7j8RKLXiJZM6QqEkY",
 "createdAt":"2015-03-25T23:57:31.859Z",
 "services":
{"password":{"bcrypt":"$2a$10$Y3C6wy5Z5nxYbVnjHDRTkeshQOhI3LjEux7s24e/Wc3SOV2e1E/7a"}
},"emails": [{"address":"qweqwe@example.com","verified":false}],
"profile":{
    "first_name":"sdfdsfds",
    "last_name":"qweqewqe"},
"roles":
    ["dc-admin"]}
```

However, once I actually try and fetch the record on the client side, or again on the server, I only get something like this(and keep in mind i have autopublish + insecure still on for development:

```
{"_id":"7j8RKLXiJZM6QqEkY","profile":{"first_name":"sdfdsfds","last_name":"qweqewqe"}}
```

If anyone could point out why maybe these emails, roles, and other fields are being deleted once the server side Meteor method has finished executing I'd be really happy!

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I've noticed Meteor.users only displays some information (such as the email address) of users who have logged in, at least when called client-side. Not sure about server-side, but logging in might "fix" both of these problems.

Comment: @Petzku looks like you're right!